# Novel in which the main character is reincarnated into a novel as a saintess. There's a white-haired male lead who is a priest at a church

Tags: story-identification, novel, isekai, reincarnation

The main character gets reincarnated into a novel as the saintess, where there's demons and dungeons. There's a white-haired male lead as well that works at the church as a priest.

Comment: You added the [novel] tag to this question, but the description sounds like the premise of a manhwa. Is this actually a manhwa or just a novel? Also, can you tell us anything more about the plot or characters? There's not a lot to go on here.

Comment: It could be a translated Korean novel. Many manhwa are adaptations of popular (web) novels so the general "feel" will be the same.

Comment: @Saiko - I see that you posted this question with an unregistered account, and since those depend entirely on cookies, it's relatively easy to lose access to them. If you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, that means you can no longer edit this question to add more details or post comments beneath it. You can regain control of the question by opening a new account (preferably a registered account) and merging it with your previous one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).